# Stop Event popagation in Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I was looking for a way to stop MouseDown event fired by an **ObjectListView** from propagation. Almost all suggestions in the net sad: use `event.Handled = true;`

However, `Handled` property is not there. I tried `Cancel` method but is not there too.

Basically, I have an ObjectListView defined as:

```
public class ObjectListView : Control
{
    //...
    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);
        //...
    }
}
```

and I used this object in one of my forms to catch mouse click event in the ObjectListView. So I added an event handler in the form:

```
partial class Form1
{
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        //...
        this.ObjectListView.MouseDown += 
            new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.ObjectListView_MouseDown);
    }
}
```

and defined within Form1 a delegate:

```
public partial class Form1
{
    private void ObjectListView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        // Stop event propagation
    }
}
```

So when I click on the ObjectListView in Form1, the Form1.ObjectListView_MouseDown method was called first and after that ObjectListView.OnMouseDown method.

I'm using .Net Framework 4.

Comment: Make the object private, so that nobody else can access it. Then it's only your code which can run

Comment: What exactly is happening? Can you share more code?

Comment: Why do you think that event is propageted?

Comment: Your `OnMouseDown` raises a *new* `MouseClick` event with `base.OnMouseClick(e)` instead of calling its parent `OnMouseDown` method. Shouldn't that be `base.OnMouseDown(e)` ?

Comment: Survival tip: if it acts weird, it's probably a bug in the code. .NET isn't broken. If such a fundamental thing as mouse clicks was broken, people would have noticed 15 years ago.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos `OnMouseDown` was fired after `ObjectListView_MouseDown`. For sure there is bug and that's why I'm asking

Comment: You are mixing up WPF and WInforms event handling.  Intention is not that clear, but if you don't want to propagate the event then simply don't call base.OnMouseDown().  Prevents any base class from seeing it and stops the MouseDown event from being raised.  The order you describe is not possible, but ObjectListView isn't exactly standard either.  Seems very unlikely the author fumbled it however, you'd have to dig through source.

Comment: @HansPassant if i remove `base.OnMouseDown()`, `OnMouseDown` method was called and `ObjectListView_MouseDown` was ignored

Comment: Right, that's what I assumed you meant with "propagating".  I suspect your experience with WPF is getting in the way.  OnMouseDown acts like WPF's PreviewMouseDown and is always called.  MouseDown is fired as long as everybody calls base.OnMouseDown